# How to install ansible-modules-extras?

Tags: ansible

I've installed ansible via the ubuntu apt package `ansible`, I am trying to use the npm module which is an extras module, which is provided only in the `ansible-modules-extras` Github repository.

How do I install ansible-modules-extras?

---

Looking at where files were installed as part of the ansible apt package, I would guess I have to merge some of the source codes folders to like `/usr/share/ansible`
 or somewhere under `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ansible`.

---

I ask this as I get this error from the Ansible output:

```
msg: Failed to find required executable npm
```

Answer (score 6):

Ansible extras are included in the Ubuntu `ansible` apt package.

The target machine must have npm installed, apt package `npm`, can be installed like so via Ansible:

```
tasks:
- name: install npm
  apt:  pkg=npm state=present
```

Comment: If i understand correctly, this task will just instruct ansible to run the apt-get command and install the 'npm' program on the target machine. How does this ensure we can call the 'maven_artifact' extra module from our playbook?

Comment: @emeraldjava IIRC, OP was asking why the npm module failed on the remote host, and the error message he got said he was missing NPM; so for his case installing NPM was the solution. I recommend trying to use the extra module you want, and look for a an error reported. you may need to turn up the verbosity.

Comment: I've been running the npm version of ansible and haven't noticed any extras I use missing. But I also don't use a lot of extras. I'm unsure of the ansible extras state in pypi.

Comment: @ThorSummoner if you've answered your own question, can you mark it as accepted for future viewers? This looks to me like exactly the right answer for your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install with python-pip, for this first time delete the ansible.

```
sudo apt-get remove ansible
```

After install python-pip

```
sudo apt-get install gcc python-pip python-dev
```

And install ansible

```
sudo pip install ansible
```

It is install the newest version. It should contain the npm mondule.